# how to show the previously checked checkbox using php

Tags: php

How to show the previously selected checkbox checked.
in my table the values are storing like   Refrigerator, Airconditioner, Television in one column

```
 <?php
    $answered="Refrigerator, Airconditioner, Television";
    $answer_options=array("Refrigerator","Airconditioner","tv");
    $ans_checked=explode(',',$answered);
    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($ans_checked);
        $checked='';

    foreach($answer_options as $a)
    {
        echo $a."<br>";
        //print_r($ans_checked);
        if(in_array($a,$ans_checked))
        {
            $checked="checked";
        }
    //echo "$a<br>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' ".$checked." >$a<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code??

Answer (score 1):

As I see it is checking all the checkboxes for this code. Once the `$checked` is set with "checked" value it remains.

You should use `else` part to unset it if not present. Or do -

```
$checked='';
if(in_array($a,$ans_checked))
{
     $checked="checked";
}
```

inside the loop.

Also you should do -

```
$ans_checked=array_map('trim', explode(',',$answered));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $answered="Refrigerator, Airconditioner, Television";
    $answered=str_replace(', ',',',$answered);
    $answer_options=array("Refrigerator","Airconditioner","tv");
    $ans_checked = explode(',', $answered);
    foreach ($answer_options as $a)
    {
        $checked = '';
        if (in_array($a, $ans_checked))
        {
            $checked = "checked";
        }
        echo $checked."<input type='checkbox' " . $checked . " >$a<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You have to notice only this second line: